# Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net... in vhdl

Tags: compiler-errors, vhdl

i wrote a code for the sha256 and get the error Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "a[31]" at syn_arit.vhd(836)
on this line digest <= temp;
i know that mean i drove into a signal in 2 different process, but i do not seem to understand where did i do that, can you help me find the issue?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity shrink_func is
    port (  clk     :   in  std_logic;
                rst     :   in  std_logic;
                maj         :   in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
                ch          :   in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
                sig0        :   in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
                sig1        :   in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
                k           :   in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
                ward        :   in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
                digest  :   out std_logic_vector(255 downto 0));
end;

architecture shrink_func of shrink_func is
    signal ready                    : std_logic := '0';
    signal h0                       : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"6a09e667";
    signal h1                       : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"bb67ae85";
    signal h2                       : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"3c6ef372";
    signal h3                       : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"a54ff53a";
    signal h4                       : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"510e527f";
    signal h5                       : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"9b05688c";
    signal h6                       : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"1f83d9ab";
    signal h7                       : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"5be0cd19";
    signal t1                       : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) ;
    signal t2                       : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) ;
    signal a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h      : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) ;
    signal temp                     : std_logic_vector(255 downto 0);

begin
process (clk,rst)
variable i : integer;
begin
    if rst = '0' then
        i := 0;
        a       <= h0;
        b       <= h1;
        c       <= h2;
        d       <= h3;
        e       <= h4;
        f       <= h5;
        g       <= h6;
        h       <= h7;
        temp    <= x"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
        t1      <= x"00000000";
        t2      <= x"00000000";
    elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
        if i = 64 then
            i := 0;
            ready <= '1';
            a       <= h0;
            b       <= h1;
            c       <= h2;
            d       <= h3;
            e       <= h4;
            f       <= h5;
            g       <= h6;
            h       <= h7;
            temp    <= x"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
            t1      <= x"00000000";
            t2      <= x"00000000";
        end if;
        if ready = '1' then
            temp <= a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h;
        end if;
        ready <= '0';
        i := i+1;
        t1 <= h + sig1 + ch + k + ward;
        t2 <= sig0 + maj;
    end if;
end process;
process(t1, t2, h, g, f, e, d, c, b, a)
begin
    h <= g;
    g <= f;
    f <= e;
    e <= d + t1;
    d <= c;
    c <= b;
    b <= a;
    a <= t1 + t2;
end process;
digest <= temp;
end;
```

Comment: You have two processes. Both of them drive a, b, .. h inclusive.

Comment: A signal is like a wire and processes can be considered sources. If you connect two sources together with a wire, you get a short-circuit.

Comment: i did tried to put the line temp <= a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h; at the second process, but it done nothing, and i tried to remove temp all together and put directly into digest, still do not worked.

Comment: Why did you think moving `temp <= a & b & etc` to the second process would fix `a <= ...` etc being in  both processes?

Comment: i understand what u saying, but when i remove that line, i have no errors, so that just made me confused.
maybe i need to rethink the all design.

Comment: if you remove that line, the signals `a`, `b`, etc are never used by the outputs, thus they are optimized away. Signals that do not exist any longer give no errors, at least: the 'multiple driver' error does not occur until later in the process.

Comment: ya i changed the reset so it will not contain the a,b,c....
now it working fine, thanks.